# Parse multi-fasta file to extract out sequences

Tags: python, fasta

I am trying to write a script in python to parse a large fasta file, I do not want to use biopython since I am learning scripting. The script needs to print the accession number, sequence length, and sequence gc content to the console. I've been able to extract the accession numbers, but am unable to extract the sequences since they're being read as lines and this is preventing me from calculating sequence length and gc content.

Could anyone help me?
I've tried to group the lines in a list, but then that creates multiple lists within a list and I'm not sure how to join them either.

```
seq=""
seqcount=0
seqlen=0
gc=0

#prompt user for file name
infile=input("Enter the name of your designated .fasta file: ")

with open(infile, "r") as fasta:
    print("\n")
    print ("Accession Number \t Sequence Length \t GC content (%)")
    for line in fasta:
       line.strip()
       if line[0]==">":
           seqcount+=1 #counts number sequences in file
           accession=line.split("|")[3] #extract accession
           seq=""
       else: 
           seq+=line[:-1]
           seqlen=len(seq)
           print(accession, "\t \t", seqlen)

print("\n")           
print("There are a total of", seqcount, "sequences in this file.")
```

Comment: What is fasta file? What format has it? I suppose not many people know it.

Comment: I think you are in a bit of a niche field, as @EugeneLisitsky said, not many people will know how a fasta file looks and won't be able to help you, your best bet if you want to learn how to doit by yourself is reading through biopython methods. https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/SeqIO/FastaIO.py

Comment: A .fasta file is a text based format commonly used to represent nucleotides or peptides. The header or gene name often looks something like this:


>gene|accession
ACTGACTAGGGACTGADEA

Comment: The humor of the situation is - i’m Familiar with python and genetics (codones triplets and so on) but I’ve never used fasta or biopython. So good definition is very useful. Thx ;)

Answer (score 2):

You were not far away from a proper code:

```
seq=""
seqcount=0

#prompt user for file name
infile=input("Enter the name of your designated .fasta file: ")

def pct_gc(s):
    gc = s.count('G') + s.count('C') + s.count('g') + s.count('c')
    total = len(s)

    return gc*100.0/total

with open(infile, "r") as fasta:
    print("\n")
    print ("Accession Number\tSequence Length\tGC content (%)")
    for line in fasta:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0]==">":
            if seq != "":
                print("{}\t{}\t{}".format(accession, pct_gc(seq), len(seq)))

            seqcount+=1 #counts number sequences in file
            accession=line.split("|")[3] #extract accession
            seq=""
        else: 
            seq+=line[:-1]

print("{}\t{}\t{}".format(accession, pct_gc(seq), len(seq)))
print("\n")           
print("There are a total of " + str(seqcount) + " sequences in this file.")
```

Things to look for:

- You don't need to update length in every iteration. Just compute it at the end.
- str.strip() does not modify the object, instead returns a stripped object
- You must use the fact that you know that you read a full sequence when you find the next one and the sequence is not empty. Is at that point that you must write the output.
- The last sequence is not finished by a new accession, so you have to process it independently at the end, after the loop.
- Use string formats or concatenate strings. If you just put strings and vars separated by commas, you get a tuple representation output.